# Does Terminal.app has Powerline glyph support?

Tags: terminal, iterm

I'm tweaking [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) config on iTerm2, which looks pleasing:
[image]

The ZSH color theme is "agnoster", the iTerm2 color preset is "Tango Dark", and I have "Use built-in Powerline glyphs" enabled. See how `~/Codes/Go` inside a bluish arrowed-shape box?

And this is what is have on built-in MacOS terminal:

[image]

Instead of a bluish arrowed-shaped box, I see a plain blue box with some garbled characters on it. I wonder if Terminal.app doesn't support this?

Comment: If you need Terminal.app to display Powerline glyphs, install a font that has Powerline glyphs.

Comment: OK got it work. First, install powerline fonts: https://github.com/powerline/fonts. Then pick one of the fonts, e.g Meslo LG.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, install [Powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) by cloning the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts
```

Then install the fonts by running the install script:

```
./install.sh
```

Then select a compatible font such as Meslo LG from the Terminal menu:

```
Terminal -> Settings... -> Profiles -> Text -> (Change Font)
```